# relationship between flopping and meta-stability

Tags: fpga, asic

While doing clock domain conversions (rate matched) we usually double flop the data to avoid meta-stable states. Double flopping just reduces the probability of meta-stability. Triple flopping will reduce it further.

How to calculate the probability/relationship between meta-stability and number of clock domain flops used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical answer to metastability queries always involves referring to articles written by [the late, great, Peter Alfke](http://www.eetimes.com/electronics-blogs/pop-blog/4230228/Peter-Alfke-Remembered--1931-2011).  In particular, [the XAPP094 appnote](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp094.pdf) - don't worry about the age of it, the theory is still the same.

There are also [numbers for some more recent families](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/PLD-Blog/Metastable-Delay-in-Virtex-FPGAs/ba-p/7996) available - although I can't see anything for the 6 and 7 series as yet.